# $group by 8 records with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have below collection

```
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-01T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 32,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-01T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-02T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-03T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-04T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-05T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-06T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-07T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-08T08:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-09T08:15:32.335Z")
}
```

I need to make an aggregation  which divides these records into pair of each 8 records and also add the `fare` of records having same date. In the above date with `2019-01-01` is having two `fares`

My expected output

```
{ data: [
{
    "fare" : 44,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-02T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-03T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-04T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-05T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-06T07:15:32.335Z")
},
{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-07T07:15:32.335Z")
},{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-08T08:15:32.335Z")
}],
data:[{
    "fare" : 12,
    "paymentMode" : "cash",
    "rideType" : "Self",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-09T08:15:32.335Z")
}
] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { d: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" }, m: { $month: "$createdAt" }, y: { $year: "$createdAt" } },
            fare: { $sum: "$fare" },
            paymentMode: { $first: "$paymentMode" },
            rideType: { $first: "$rideType" },
            userId: { $first: "$userId" },
            createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { createdAt: 1 }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            docs: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [0,  { $ceil: { $divide: [ { $size: "$docs" }, 8 ] } } ] },
                    as: "arrayStart",
                    in: {
                        $slice: [ "$docs", { $multiply: [ "$$arrayStart", 8 ] }, 8 ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$docs"
    }
])
```

Basically you want to sum `fares` by day so you need to get that day based on date type using [$dayOfMonth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/index.html), [$month](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/index.html) and [$year](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/index.html) operators. Then you need to get 8-element buckets so you can merge all documents into single array ([$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with `_id` set to `null`). Then you can simply calculate how many "buckets" you need (using [$ceil](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ceil/index.html) and [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html)) and [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/index.html) long array into 8-element arrays. In the last step you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get 8-elements array per final document. Output:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "docs" : [
        {
            "fare" : 44,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-01T07:15:32.335Z")
        },
        {
            "fare" : 12,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-02T07:15:32.335Z")
        },
        {
            "fare" : 12,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-03T07:15:32.335Z")
        },
        {
            "fare" : 12,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-04T07:15:32.335Z")
        },
        {
            "fare" : 12,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-05T07:15:32.335Z")
        },
        {
            "fare" : 12,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-06T07:15:32.335Z")
        },
        {
            "fare" : 12,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-07T07:15:32.335Z")
        },
        {
            "fare" : 12,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-08T08:15:32.335Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : null,
    "docs" : [
        {
            "fare" : 12,
            "paymentMode" : "cash",
            "rideType" : "Self",
            "userId" : ObjectId("5c25c5fa12430a348459a3d7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-09T08:15:32.335Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Great!!! mickl... One question Can I use `$facet` instead of `$push` ROOT document. That will be more efficient

Comment: @Profer I don't think so, `$facet` allows you to run multiple parallel aggregation pipelines while `$push` just adds whole document to an array

Comment: But `$push`ing whole document into single array in a `$group` stage will extend the 16MB BSON limit.

Comment: @Profer you need to test that, however "The limit only applies to the returned documents; during the pipeline processing, the documents may exceed this size"  from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/

Comment: Cool mickl **The limit only applies to the returned documents; during the pipeline processing, the documents may exceed this size** That's tremendous new to me.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to use the [$bucketAuto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/#pipe._S_bucket) pipe instead of a regular group step. For this, you might have to pre-calculate the amount of buckets needed, based on your document count. E.g. If the count is 84, then the bucketCount would be something like `ceil(84/8) = 11`. I haven't found an elegant way to do this in the same aggregation, yet.

**UPDATE:**
Here is an example for putting your documents in two buckets

```
db.getCollection('probands').aggregate([
{   $sort : {'_id' : -1}}, // not necessary, but probably nice
{
    $bucketAuto : {
        groupBy: '$_id', // this create "groups" of one element each
        buckets: 2, // calculate this value beforehand
        output: {
            data : {
                $push : { // pushes the wanted fields into the data array
                    '_id': '$_id',
                    'fare' : '$fare',
                    'paymentMode' : '$paymentMode',
                    'createdAt' : '$createdAt',
                    'rideType': '$rideType',
                    'userId': '$userId',
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{ $project: {_id: 0, data : 1}}
])
```

The calculation of the fare is a different question, but probably easier than this one by using a regular `$group` step + `$sum`.

Comment: You got it... Could you show an example please. How can I make this

Comment: I updated my answer. I also realized that `$bucketAuto` should be even better in your use-case.